# Type Mismatch error setting Excel app calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that gets or starts Excel from Visio using VBA and creates a workbook to accompany the active Visio drawing.

When the macro goes to turn off Excel auto calculation I get a type mismatch error, but it doesn't always give that error.

Why does the code work sometimes, and not others?

```
Dim XLCalcMode As Long
XLCalcMode = XLApp.Calculation
XLApp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Answer (score 6):

The Excel application has to have at least one workbook open before you can set the Calculation property on the Application object.

Move the .Calculation setting to after there's a workbook open.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Visio and I go on with the general assumption that it doesn't share Excel enumerations, like `XlCalculation` is

So you:

- either use *actual* enumeration values

  for instance xlCalculationManual has a value of -4135, then you want to code

  ```
  XLApp.Calculation = -4135
  ```
- or use Excel enumerations name by referencing Excel Application object

  ```
  XLApp.Calculation = XLApp.xlCalculationManual
  ```

Comment: I use late binding, but I do have all the Excel constants defined.  Instead I found that it's just not possible to set the .Calculation property on Excel's Application unless there's a workbook open.